# Summing a field from all tables in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database called "bookfeather."  It contains 56 tables.  Each table has the following structure:

```
id site votes_up votes_down
```

The value for "site" is a book title.  The value for "votes_up" is an integer.  Sometimes a unique value for "site" appears in more than one table.

For each unique value "site" in the entire database, I would like to sum "votes_up" from all 56 tables.  Then I would like to print the top 25 values for "site" ranked by total "votes_up".

How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Dare I ask why you have 56 tables with identical structure, as opposed to a single table with 1 extra field to indicate what table the record *would* be in?

Comment: I agree with Dav, you should probably redesign your database.

Comment: That's just how I set it up.  I allow users to add tables to the database, so I expect the number of tables to increase beyond 56.

Comment: +1 for redesign. This is denormalized structure.

Comment: Everything works great and it would be a lot of work to re-design at this point.  For now, is there a way to do what I want with the current structure?

Comment: The design is badly broken. It isn't really sensible to iterate across tables.  It's so much simpler to have one table with an extra column instead of 55 identical tables.

Comment: This is almost identical to your other question. I would think it would make more sense if you combined both questions into one and had one of them (this one) closed.  In the other question you explained why there are so many tables.

Comment: +1 for redesign.  "Works great" is subjective, and not lots of work to correct.  The work will be having to add a new table for every new book.  It's a "how not to design databases" case study.

Comment: If I had just one table, it would end up being gigantic.  The total number of rows is the same.  I think it's more manageable to have 56 mid-size tables than one enormous table.

Comment: @ John - Have you spent time thinking conceptually about the types of data you are storing?  If every table has the same structure, which it sounds like it does, they all ought to be under the same table.  It's a relational database design maxim.

Comment: Databases are designed to handle gigantic tables far more than they're designed to handle gigantic queries across large numbers of tables.

Comment: @ John - Typically complexity is controlled via "views" on your data, not by generating multiple tables in relational database design.

Comment: Define "gigantic".  Relational databases with terabytes of data are common.  Is that scale you're going to exceed?

Comment: @ Dav.  Fair enough.  I'm self-taught, and it was easier for me to conceptualize the database with lots of tables.  At this point, I don't want to go back and change all of my code.  MySQL seems to work plenty fast with the structure I'm using.

Comment: "At this point, I don't want to go back and change all of my code" - I'd still advise that you do so, because it'll be easier now than later.

Comment: @John: "I'm self-taught" doesn't mean you can't learn.  Here's a chance to learn a better design.

Comment: Reminds me of this article from The Daily WTF: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/A_Database_0x27_s_Database.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a PHP code snip that should get it done.
I have not tested it so it might have some typos and stuff, make sure you replace DB_NAME

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
$tables = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tables[] = '`'.$row["Tables_in_DB_NAME"].'`';

}

$subQuery = "SELECT site, votes_up FROM ".implode(" UNION ALL SELECT site, votes_up FROM ",$tables);
// Create one query that gets the data you need
$sqlStr = "SELECT site, sum(votes_up) sumVotesUp
            FROM (
            ".$subQuery." ) subQuery
           GROUP BY site ORDER BY sum(votes_up) DESC LIMIT 25";
$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);
$arr = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $arr[] = $row["site"]." - ".$row["sumVotesUp"];
} 
print_r($arr)
```

Comment: I tried printing out $result in a table but I got an error message.  Do you know what code I should use?  Thanks

Comment: you should run over it using something like:
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[] = array("site"=> $row["site"],"sumVotesUp" => $row["sumVotesUp"]);
}
print_r($arr);
for this to work you should add an alias to the sum(votes_up) in the query that goes into $sqlStr. I'll fix it in my answer.

Comment: I also added this snip to the answer's code so you could see it with proper formatting

Comment: I'm getting an error message for the line with "while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) ".   Up above, I'm using "$tables[] = $row1["Tables_in_bookfeather"];"... I'm not sure if this is right.  Is it?

Comment: if that's your database name then it should be good. 
you get it in the first while(...mysql_fetch_assoc...) or the second one?
try printing out mysql_error() for getting more hints

Comment: can you please print mysql_error() right after the $result=mysql_query($sqlStr); line?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ever UNION ALL SELECT site, votes_up FROM biography UNION ALL SELECT site, votes'

Comment: ok, I think I've fixed it. look at my answer, I've changed the $subQuery = ... line

Comment: uhm, very weird.  any chance you could print $sqlStr and paste it to pastebin.com?

Comment: what's the url? not very easy to find stuff there

Comment: oh. you got spaces in your table names :S ok, check my change in the $tables[]=.. line. I've added backticks around the table names so it'd accept spaces.

Comment: ok... almost there.  Now, it prints the info I want, but each book looks like "Array ( [0] => Array ( [site] => gone with the wind [sumVotesUp] => 63".  How could I get it to look like "gone with the wind 63"?

Comment: BTW, you could also just replace it with 

echo $row["site"]." - ".$row["sumVotesUp"]."\n";

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (warning: Extremely poor SQL ahead)

```
select site, sum(votes_up) votes_up
from (
    select site, votes_up from table_1
    UNION
    select site, votes_up from table_2
    UNION
    ...
    UNION
    select site, votes_up from table_56
) group by site order by sum(votes_up) desc limit 25
```

But, as Dav asked, does your data *have* to be like this? There are much more efficient ways of storing this kind of data.

Edit: You just mentioned in a comment that you expect there to be more than 56 tables in the future -- I would look into MySQL limits on how many tables you can UNION before going forward with this kind of SQL.

Comment: I allow users to add tables to the database.  Is there a way I could make the code allow unions up until the last table, regardless of how many there are in the database?

Comment: It's not for a union, but the numbers are likely to be similar... "The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join is 61. This also applies to the number of tables that can be referenced in the definition of a view. This also applies to LEFT and RIGHT OUTER JOINS." For MySQL 5.0

Comment: Another source says "There is a limit of "256 tables per SELECT statement". You can use more than 256 tables in a query with UNION statements, but such a query cannot be used as a view or as a subquery for a SELECT statement. If you use such a query directly, you may hit a stack space limit of the query optimizer at around 1300-1500 SELECT-s."

Answer (score 0):

The UNION part of Ian Clelland answer can be generated using a statement like the following. The table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS has a column TABLE_NAME to get all tables.

```
select * from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema not like 'informat%'
and column_name like 'VOTES_UP'
```

Join all inner SELECT with UNION ALL instead of UNION. UNION is doing an implicit DISTINCT (on oracle).

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be to iterate over all your tables (using a SQL `SHOW TABLES` statement or similar) in PHP, then for every table, iterate over the rows (`SELECT site,votes_up FROM $table`). Then, for every row, check the site against an array that you're building with sites as keys and votes up as values. If the site is already in the array, increment its votes appropriately; otherwise, add it.

Vaguely PHP-like pseudocode:

```
// Build an empty array for use later
$votes_array = empty_array();

// Get all the tables and iterate over them
$tables = query("SHOW TABLES");
for($table in $tables) {
    $rows = query("SELECT site,votes_up FROM $table");

    // Iterate over the rows in each table
    for($row in $rows) {
          $site = $row['site'];
          $votes = $row['votes_up'];

         // If the site is already in the array, increment votes; otherwise, add it
         if(exists_in_array($site, $votes_array)) {
             $votes_array[$site] += $votes;
         } else {
             insert_into_array($site => $votes);
         }
    }
}

// Get the sites and votes as lists, and print out the top 25
$sorted_sites = array_keys($votes_array);
$sorted_votes = array_values($votes_array);
for($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) {
    print "Site " . $sorted_sites[$i] . " has " . $sorted_votes[$i] . " votes";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"I allow users to add tables to the database." - I hope all your users are benevolent and trustworthy and capable.  Do you worry about people dropping or truncating tables, creating incorrect new tables that break your code, or other things like that?  What kind of security do you have when users can log right into your database and change the schema?

Here's a [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) on relational database normalization.  Maybe it'll help.

Just in case someone else that comes after you wants to find what this could have looked like, here's a single table that could do what you want:

```
create database bookfeather;
create user bookfeather identified by 'bookfeather';
grant all on bookfeather.* to 'bookfeather'@'%';

use bookfeather;

create table if not exists book
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    title varchar(255) not null default '',
    upvotes integer not null default 0,
    downvotes integer not null default 0,
    primary key(id),
    unique(title)
);
```

You'd vote a title up or down with an UPDATE:

```
update book set upvotes = upvotes + 1 where id = ?
```

Adding a new book is as easy as adding another row:

```
insert into book(title) values('grails in action')
```

I'd strongly urge that you reconsider.